# cannot set themePath with ace-builds

Tags: python, ace-editor

I am able to get the themePath in ace-editor ( I am using the nom ace-builds bundle ) to work. I can set the base path and the editor loads up fine, however it is still looking for the themes in the default directory.

```
import ace
import ace from 'ace-builds'
import {Range, EditSession} from 'ace-builds'

// import modes that you want to include into your main bundle
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-yaml";

// import webpack resolver to dynamically load modes,
   you need to install file-loader for this to work!
   import "ace-builds/webpack-resolver";

ace.config.set("themePath","../static/js");
ace.config.set("basePath","../static/js");
ace.config.set("modePath","../static/js");

var editor = ace.edit("ace_editor_playbook", {
        maxLines: 25,
        minLines: 25,
        value: "---" + "\n",
        mode: "ace/mode/yaml",
        theme: "ace/theme/vibrant_ink",
        bug: 1
      })
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

themePath is not used because https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/webpack-resolver.js explicitely sets paths of all themes. If you want to use themePath do not load the webpack-resolver